# How to switch between GoPro WLAN and Home network WLAN?

Tags: wifi, wpa-supplicant

In my setup I want to switch between my GoPro camera WLAN (to control GoPro camera) and my Home WLAN (to send recorded images by mail).

I tried to use the script described in [How to switch back and forth between 2 WLANs, of which 1 hidden?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/106410/how-to-switch-back-and-forth-between-2-wlans-of-which-1-hidden) but have no success. I always stick with my home network.

I have wpa_supplicant.conf with the following definitions:

```
ctrl_interface=DIR=/var/run/wpa_supplicant GROUP=netdev
update_config=0
country=CH

network={
    ssid="UPC7529264"
    scan_ssid=1
    psk="passwordHome"
    key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
}

network={
    ssid="HERO7Black"
    psk="passwordGoPro"
    key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
```

I understand that network 0 is UPC7529264, while network 1 is HERO7Black. 
While beeing connected to UPC7529264 and executing `switchnetwork.sh EXTERNAL` I would have expected the network to switch to the GoPro Network. But nothing happens. I keep with UPC7529264:

```
$ sudo bash ./switchnetwork.sh EXTERNAL
SWITCHING TO NETWORK ID 1
Selected interface 'p2p-dev-wlan0'
OK
Selected interface 'p2p-dev-wlan0'
OK

$ iw dev wlan0 info
Interface wlan0
    ifindex 3
    wdev 0x1
    addr 76:2c:e4:30:f7:83
    ssid UPC7529264
    type managed
    wiphy 0
    channel 44 (5220 MHz), width: 40 MHz, center1: 5230 MHz
    txpower 31.00 dBm
```

Any ideas what configuration could prevent the switch?

@Ingo : Sorry for the bad formating in the comment. 
I see your point, but it seems I am in fact changing the wlan0 network:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ ./switch2gopro.sh
WPA process killed 
PascalHERO7 connected 
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ wpa_cli -iwlan0 status 
bssid=06:41:69:d7:d1:d6 freq=2437 
ssid=PascalHERO7 
... 
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ ./switch2home.sh 
WPA process killed 
UPC Home connected 
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ wpa_cli -iwlan0 status 
bssid=38:43:7d:40:06:62 
freq=2462 
ssid=UPC7529264 
...
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ wpa_cli status 
Selected interface 'p2p-dev-wlan0' 
wpa_state=DISCONNECTED 
...
```

Comment: Have a look at the `priority=nnn` option in `/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf` you can use that to choose a preferred network (bigger number is more preferred). Otherwise you'll have to kill wpa_supplicant and restart it with a new config file.

Comment: Priority is not an option, since I want to switch depending on the usage I have. There are two wpa_supplicant processes.
```
/sbin/wpa_supplicant -u -s -O /run/wpa_supplicant
wpa_supplicant -B -c/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf -iwlan0 -Dnl80211,wext
```
I killed both and restarted only a the 2nd with special ```wpa_gopro.conf``` or  ```wpa_home.conf``` 
This works, but on the desktop another symbol is shown (up/down arrow instead of WLAN wave symbol) and "No AP found - scanning...".

Answer (score 2):

It seems you are selecting the wrong interface `p2p-dev-wlan0` on your RasPi. This is an interface for a peer to peer connection, but your networks are managed. You can show all available interfaces with (example from my raspi):

```
rpi ~$ iw dev
phy#0
        Unnamed/non-netdev interface
                wdev 0x2
                addr 42:43:06:8d:8c:0e
                type P2P-device
                txpower 31.00 dBm
        Interface wlan0
                ifindex 4
                wdev 0x1
                addr 02:e1:05:80:97:72
                ssid TestNet
                type managed
                channel 6 (2437 MHz), width: 20 MHz, center1: 2437 MHz
                txpower 31.00 dBm
```

The first one is the virtual interface `p2p-dev-wlan0` and selected first if no interface to manage is specified. Look where you have to select `wlan0` in your setup. With `wpa_cli` you will see the difference using its option `-iwlan0`:

```
rpi ~$ wpa_cli status
Selected interface 'p2p-dev-wlan0'
wpa_state=DISCONNECTED
p2p_device_address=42:43:06:8d:8c:0e
address=42:43:06:8d:8c:0e
uuid=cf397134-9e90-5387-92f2-8995cb071d05

rpi ~$ wpa_cli -iwlan0 status
bssid=dc:a6:32:01:db:ed
freq=2437
ssid=TestNet
id=0
mode=station
pairwise_cipher=CCMP
group_cipher=TKIP
key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
wpa_state=COMPLETED
p2p_device_address=42:43:06:8d:8c:0e
address=02:e1:05:80:97:72
uuid=cf397134-9e90-5387-92f2-8995cb071d05
```

Comment: I see your point, but it seems I am in fact changing the wlan0 network: 
`pi@raspberrypi:~ $ ./switch2gopro.sh
WPA process killed
PascalHERO7 connected
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ wpa_cli -iwlan0 status
bssid=06:41:69:d7:d1:d6
freq=2437
ssid=PascalHERO7
...
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ ./switch2home.sh 
WPA process killed
UPC Home connected
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ wpa_cli -iwlan0 status
bssid=38:43:7d:40:06:62
freq=2462
ssid=UPC7529264

pi@raspberrypi:~ $ wpa_cli status
Selected interface 'p2p-dev-wlan0'
wpa_state=DISCONNECTED
...`

Comment: @P-ascii Sorry, but your comment is unreadable. Please [edit](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/posts/111235/edit) your question and add it there.